# Sqlite3 и кавычки при INSERT

Tags: ios, sqlite3

Каким образом в БД можно добавлять строки, если в них содержатся кавычки " ?

Comment: Я конечно не спец по iOS но в драйвер плейсходеров не завезли?

а так \"

Answer (score 1):

Добавлять текст с кавычками и другими символами можно, с применением экранирования. Могу предложить вам функцию для формирования sql запроса, которая возвращает строку `char*` для дальнейшего использования в `sqlite3_exec(...)`.

```
-(char*) prepare_INSERT_QueryWithParams:(NSDictionary*) params intoTable:(NSString*) table
{
    NSArray *key = [params allKeys];
    NSMutableString *strColums = [[key firstObject] mutableCopy];
    NSString *firstValue = params[[key firstObject]]?:@"";
    NSMutableString *strValues = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"", firstValue] mutableCopy];
    for (int i=1; i<params.count; i++)
    {
        [strColums appendFormat:@",%@",key[i]];
        NSString *value = params[key[i]];
        if (value.class == NSString.class)
            value = [value stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\"\""]?:@"";

        [strValues appendFormat:@",\"%@\"",value];
    }
    return (char*)[[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO %@(%@) values(%@)", table, strColums, strValues] UTF8String];
}
```

Вот пример использования функции:

```
char *sqlInsertQuery = [self prepare_INSERT_QueryWithParams:@{
                                                                 @"colom1": @"value \'1",
                                                                 @"colom2": @"value \"2",
                                                              }
                                                  intoTable:@"table_name"];

printf("%s",sqlInsertQuery); //INSERT INTO table_name(colom1,colom2) values("value '1","value "2")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('main.db')
conn.text_factory = str
```

и можно хоть иероглифы добавлять

Answer (score -1):

например

```
insert into table(a) values ('A"');
```

или

```
insert into table(a) values ("A'");
```

или же

```
insert into table(a) values ('A''');
```

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky для меня это был не на столько теоретический вопрос, что в моём случае ответ с примером мне был бы достаточен. Но все же спасибо за совет.